# What is the purpose of console.log if it doesn't change anything about the website?

Tags: javascript

I am VERY new to JS. I am using CodeAcademy currently (the free one because i'm currently poor) to learn some basics. I am able to log things to the console. Create var and stuff like that. I just don't understand how console.log is useful on a site. It prints to the console but what's the point if it doesn't show up on the actual site?

I've searched and searched for this answer all over and just can't find an answer. I feel like a deer caught in headlights that just can't move fwd.

Comment: Welcome to SO! helps with debugging, also easy way to get things working and see if it is doing what you want.

Answer (score 1):

console.log is used for debugging. Many developers use it to print out warnings and errors. You can read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_console_log.asp

Answer (score 0):

The developer console ist merely used for making your life as a developer easier. It helps you track down bugs in your code faster and makes logging your applications' state possible.

Answer (score 0):

In the early days of JS, the debugging was performed through **alert()** function which was pretty annoying and hard to work with (now it is an obsolete practice).

**console.log** is nothing but a feature for debugging purposes. For example, let's say you want to have a button that adds a cool effect to your page. You can for instance log something to the console to detect that the click really happens. For instance:

```js
$('#coolButton').click(function() {
  console.log('#coolButton was clicked');
  // other code
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="coolButton">Apply cool effect</button>
```

Other example would be when you are receiving from a server some data, you try to sort it based on a custom field and you get some errors, that something is `undefined`. You are 100% sure that you are sorting the data OK, so what's the problem? Well, you can use `console.log` to log some of your objects and see why you are getting errors. For example:

```js
let toSort = [
  {"type": "A", "info": {"value": 5}},
  {"type": "B", "info": {"value": 2}},
  {"type": "C", "info": {"value": 8}},
  {"type": "C", "info": {"value": -1}},
  {"type": "B"},
  // {"type": "B", "info": {"value": 13}},
  {"type": "A", "info": {"value": 10}}]
  
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.info.value < b.info.value)
    return -1;
  if (a.info.value > b.info.value)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

toSort.forEach((o, i) => {
  console.log("Object " + i + ": " + o.type + "->" + o.info.value);
});
    
toSort.sort(compare);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Sort will get => `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"` because the previous from the last element does not have an info property. How to we know this? We iterated the array and printed the objects and their value and we observed we have an undefined on one of them. (in the real life, that array might come from a server that is node made by you so you might want to inspect the data to know how to work with it; If you comment the line and un-comment the commented one, it will work).

Cheers!

Comment: thank you for your help and putting up with a total noob